# Showing read-only or non-modifiable status in status line

Tags: statusline, options

I am building my statusline.  Previously I used functions to return information, but recently I learnt that these can be done in one line. For example:

```
set statusline+=%{&modified?'\ \ [+]':''}
```

I need to find if file is readonly or non-modifiable, like the example above. Right now I have:

```
set statusline+=%{&readonly?'\ ':''}\ 
```

But I need something like this:

```
set statusline+=%{(&readonly || !&modifiable)?'\ ':''}\ 
```

But I get an error: `unclosed expression sequence`.  What's the situation here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full error gives you a hint as to the problem:

```
E540: Unclosed expression sequence: statusline=%{(&readonly
```

You cannot include unescaped space characters in `:set` commands, because Vim interprets them as the end of the setting. (See `:h option-backslash`.)

The quickest solution is to escape your space characters (or just remove them! `(&readonly||!&modifiable)` will evaluate fine), but I prefer to use `:let`:

```
let &statusline .= '%{(&readonly || !&modifiable) ? " " : ""} '
```

(See `:h :let-option`)